# OpenCV - cv2.perspectiveTransform() not working for all the images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, homography

I used PerspectiveTransform to draw an outline around the detected image.

The `cv2.perspectiveTransform()` is able to draw a rectangle only for a few detected images but not for all the images.

Some of the detected images are not showing up with an outline.

What might be the reason of missing it?

Does it assume that the points may be outside the camera view and detected just the image without projecting an outline?

[image]

Comment: are all your images of type `float`?

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes all the images are 32 bit floats.

Comment: Maybe add some example images.

Comment: @AdiShavit Added example images.

Comment: Where are the rectangles in this image?  An you show a success and a failure case?